# Why is this infinite loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, linked-list, infinite-loop

Sorry, maybe this is a newbie question. But it's an assignment from my lecturer and the due date is tomorrow. I've tried many ways and track the output but it still resulted in infinite loop. Please help.

The question asked:

> Remove the passed students from studentList and move them to a new LinkedList passList

Main Application:

```
StudentLinkedList failList = studentList; //assume studentList is already existed with some data
StudentLinkedList passList = new StudentLinkedList();

Student s = (Student)studentList.removeFirst(); //the return type was Object (it was user-defined LinkedList)
//so i use dynamic binding to change it to student
while(s != null) {
  if(s.isPass()) { //return true if student passed
    System.out.println("pass"); //i track my output with this
    passList.addFirst(s);
  } else {
    System.out.println("fail"); //track output
    failList.addFirst(s);
  }
  s = (Student)studentList.removeFirst();
}
```

The output was infinite loop between fail and pass which I assume the loop was because the s was never null.

Here's remove first method definition:

```
public Object removeFirst() {
   if(head == null) { //check if the list was empty
     return null;
   } else {
     current = head;
     head = head.next;
     if(head == null) {
        tail = null;
     }
     return current.element;
   }
}
```

I'm in my second year learning java. Your help will be appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: Try outputting what ```s``` is each time you call the ```.removeFirst()``` function, that way you will be able to see what it is and why it is not equalling ```null```. Also, not sure if ```new StudentLinkedList;``` outputs what you expect it to.

Comment: @ruakh I'm sorry that was a typing error when I'm trying to add the comment I must've accidentally removed the (). I've fixed it. The problem still same.

Comment: @Ryan I've added what u asked after the ```s``` and it turns out it prints an infinite loop of the first student that failed in the list. Does the removeFirst() definition have something wrong?

Comment: Newbie questions are very welcome as long as they are well researched and explained. Yours is fine.

Comment: Use iterator pattern and try to avoid while loop. If "s" is object, then do not worry about memory, and don't remove students from students list - just iterate over students, and create two additional lists. And for the future - isPass() should not be a part of Student object, there should be additional object StudentResult and result calculation should be done in separate stateless component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code, you are assigning `StudentLinkedList failList = studentList;`. This does not create a copy of `studentList` and does not allocate new memory, but rather means that `failList` points to `studentList`.

So any changes made in `failList` are actually being changed in `studentList`.

This would make sense to why there is an infinite loop when it hits a student that has failed since you are actually just adding the student back to the initial `studentList` and not a newly created `failList` as intended.

Comment: It worked! I use while loop to copy each data to another list. My bad I literally forgot that even my lecturer had taught me that last year. Thank you very much! As a student, I will remember to not just simply assign like ```a = b;``` to copy something in the future. Thank you again.